# Inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{\frac{1}{s}-s}$

Tags: laplace-transform, residue-calculus, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

doing some work on a PDE system I have stumbled across a Laplace transform which I'm not sure how to invert:
$$
F(s) = e^{\frac{1}{s}-s}
$$
I can't find it in any table and the strong singular growth for $s=0$ makes me think that perhaps the inverse doesn't exist? Does it exist? And if it does, how can I find it?

Thanks for your help,

Maxi

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $$e^{s-1/s}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{e^{-s}}{k! s^k}$$ and use $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)\}=e^{-sa}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\\\mathcal{L}\{t^k H(t)\}=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{s^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Yes, thanks @user1952009 for pointing that out. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! That a very pretty solution!

Comment: I apologize for doing this because I hate to be seen disparaging another answer, but I really do not see how you would recover the ILT from your scheme.  Maybe I am simple-minded about this but perhaps could you carry out a few more steps just so it is clear how to recover the ILT using your methodology?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse most definitely exists.  Write the integrand of the ILT in its Laurent expansion about $s=0$ as follows:

$$F(s) e^{s t} = e^{\frac1s} e^{(t-1) s} = \left (1+\frac1s +\frac1{2! s^2} + \frac1{3! s^3}+\cdots \right ) \left [1+(t-1) s+\frac1{2!} (t-1)^2 s^2 + \cdots \right ]$$

The ILT is simply the residue of the integrand at $s=0$, or namely the coefficient of $s^{-1}$ in the above expansion.  This coefficient is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(t-1)^{k}}{k!(k+1)!} H(t-1) = \frac{I_1\left (2 \sqrt{t-1} \right )}{\sqrt{t-1}} H(t-1)$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside function and $I_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of first order.